# How can I make a realistic lightsaber?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I want to make a lightsaber where the edjes/sides are more red and in the middle it is white, so I tried using the layer weight node with a color ramp and I got a nice result when looking from the front, but when I look sideways its all red without any white in the middle (first picture). (My material  nodes are shown in the second picture). Any solutions? I have another idea but I don't think it will look that good. I was thinking to add bloom in the final render and use only an emission shader with red color and strength a big number like 200 so it would look white, and the bloom would add that red color around it.[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USxvl.png)

[image: second picture]

I am using cycles

Comment: For realism, I'd suggest going for your second idea - ie, a bright emission shader with bloom/fog glow added in the compositor. This will almost undoubtedly produce more 'realistic' results that trying to fake it with layer weight or similar. I suppose one consideration would be whether it's for a still image or animated - if 'still' then you could potentially tweak the faking so as to look good under your specific situation. If it's to animate then you want something that will work in a wide range of situations - so the 'real world' solution (bright emission with fog glow) will be better.

Comment: I've made light sabers before, and the super bight emission (200 or so) always works well for my purposes. Always white in the center, with the appropriate color glow.

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you set the emission to a large number, it will shine very bright in the scene on other object, which you may want, however, I used a fresnel input to find the outer edges and used a color ramp to convert them to red and white.

Comment: Thank you both for the help! I will try both of them and see which one I prefer.